# facebook login using custom listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make a custom login-logut button, and I'm not sure I'm implementing the facebook JS API correctly:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<button id="fb-login">Login</button>
<script>

(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());


window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '160525653984605', status: true, cookie: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            $("#fb-login").html = "Logout";
            $("#fb-login").unbind();
            $("#fb-login").bind("click", logout);
            console.log('User is logged in.');
        }

          else {
            $("#fb-login").unbind();
            $("#fb-login").bind("click", login);
            console.log('User is not logged in.');
        }
    });
  };

function login(){
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response) {
                console.log('Login success. Checking auth_nonce...');
        //      window.location = "http://wall-et.com/index.php/test/welcome/"
                $("#fb-login").html = 'Logout';
            }
            else {
                console.log('Login cancelled.')
            }
        },
        {auth_type: 'reauthenticate', auth_nonce: 'abcd1234' });
}

function logout(){
        FB.logout(function(response) {
            $("#fb-login").html = "Login";
    });
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two function login,
change to logout ;)